# Вывод данных в файл через сервер C#

Tags: c#

Народ, подскажите пожалуйста, почему мои данные выводятся в файл в одну строку, а не происходит переноса на новую строку, к тому же пробел исчез..как выглядит сейчас:

0: 28.06.2016 22:42:511: 28.06.2016 22:42:522: 28.06.2016 22:42:533: 28.06.2016 22:42:544: 28.06.2016 22:42:55

А должно выводиться так:

0: 28.06.2016 22:42:51

1: 28.06.2016 22:42:52

2: 28.06.2016 22:42:53

3: 28.06.2016 22:42:54

4: 28.06.2016 22:42:55

Суть в том, что от клиента приходят эти данные на сервак, в переменную message..сервер их записывает в файл, затем через минуту происходит перезапись..

```
class Program
{
    const int port = 8888;
    static TcpListener listener;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Interval = 10000;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Start();

            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
            listener.Start();
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            Console.WriteLine("Ожидание подключений...");

            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                ClientObject clientObject = new ClientObject(client);

                // создаем новый поток для обслуживания нового клиента
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(clientObject.Process));
                clientThread.Start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (listener != null)
                listener.Stop();
        }
    }
    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check file access
        //delete file's old content
        var file = new FileInfo("log.txt");
        try
        {
            //stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"log.txt");


            StringBuilder newLines = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var date = Convert.ToDateTime(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(' ') + 1));
                var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
                if(date>=currentTime.AddMinutes(-1))
                {
                    newLines.Append(line + "\n");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Cleaning...");
            using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream("log.txt", FileMode.Create))
            {
                // запись массива байтов в файл
                byte[] array = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(newLines.ToString());
                fstream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            //the file is unavailable because it is:
            //still being written to
            //or being processed by another thread
            //or does not exist (has already been processed)
        }
    }
}
```

И код класса ClientObject

```
public class ClientObject
{
    public TcpClient client;
    public ClientObject(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        client = tcpClient;
    }
    public void Process()
    {
        NetworkStream stream = null;
        try
        {
            stream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] data = new byte[64]; // буфер для получаемых данных
            while (true)
            {
                // получаем сообщение
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                int bytes = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                }
                while (stream.DataAvailable);

                string message = builder.ToString() + "\n";

                Console.WriteLine("Записываю в log {0}", message);

                try
                {
                    using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream("log.txt", FileMode.Append))
                    {
                        // преобразуем строку в байты
                        byte[] array = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message);
                        // запись массива байтов в файл
                        fstream.Write(array, 0, array.Length);
                        //Console.WriteLine("Текст записан в файл");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    // ERROR MESSAGE TO CLIENT
                    //message = ex.Message;
                    //data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                    //stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }

                // отправляем обратно сообщение в верхнем регистре
                //message = message.Substring(message.IndexOf(':') + 1).Trim().ToUpper();
                //data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);
                //stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
            if (client != null)
                client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема насчет корректной записи решена! Нужно было добавить \r\n.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста по поводу времени перезаписи, нужно чтоб через минуту, но у меня через секунд 5-6 перезаписывает, хотя я пытался вычислить разницу времени..

Comment: Самый простой способ завести класс в котором будут храниться ваши принимаемые данные и время последней записи и в цикле, либо как то еще периодически проверять текущее время. Да и в вашем коде стоит 10000 млс, в переводе - это 10 секунд.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте `Environment.NewLine` (или `\r\n`). Да, и раз вы уже нашли ответ на вопрос, то закройте его! Висит в списках неотвеченных, зашел сюда только из-за этого.